# Numpy: sorting matrix like list of lists, or: sort matrix by rows

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have a `numpy` matrix that contains row vectors.  I want to sort the matrix by its rows, like Python would sort a list of lists:

```
import numpy as np
def sortx(a):
    return np.array(sorted([list(i) for i in a]))

a = np.array([[1,4,0,2],[0,2,3,1]])
print(sortx(a))
```

Output:

```
[[0 2 3 1]
 [1 4 0 2]]
```

Is there a `numpy` equivalent of my `sortx()` function so I don't have to convert the data twice?

Comment: Your sortx can be slightly improved by `return np.array(sorted(a.tolist()))`

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use numpy's `lexsort`:

```
a=a[np.lexsort(a[:,::-1].T)]
```

On my machine this was about four times faster than your `sortx` method when applied to a 4x4 matrix. On a matrix with 100 rows, the speed difference is even more significant.

```
arr=np.random.randint(0,100,(100,4))
%timeit np.lexsort(arr[:,::-1].T)
#6.29 µs +- 27.1ns
% timeit sortx(arr)
# 112µs +- 1.2µs
```

---

**Edit:**

Andyk suggested an improved version of the `sortx()` method.

```
def sortx_andyk(a):
    return np.array(sorted(a.tolist())
```

Timing of this method:

```
%timeit sortx_andryk(arr)
# 43µs +- 169ns
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.sort(arr, axis=0)`
In your case

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,4,0,2],[0,2,3,1]])
np.sort(a, axis=0)
```

**Edit**

I misunderstood the question, even though I do not have an exact answer for your question, you might be able to use `argsort`. This returns the indices in to sort your array. However, it only does this based on an axis. It is possible to use this to sort your arrays based on a specific column, e.g. the first. Then you would use it as such

```
a = a[a.argsort(axis=0)[:, 0]]
```

where `[:, 0]` specifies the column by which to sort, i.e. `[:, n]` will sort on the `n`-th column.

Comment: Nope, that will sort all column **entries**. I want to bring the row **vectors** into order.

Comment: In that case I misunderstood the question, I do not have a complete answer for your problem but added a suggestion to my original answer that might help.

Comment: But as you say, this will only sort based on one column, but I need a sort based on the whole vector's contents.

Comment: True, you could do this by applying numpy argsort sorting from last column to first column. This will produce the desired result, but for long arrays I doubt it will be faster than converting to a regular list.